# How to update state array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, material-table

I am making a App in Reactjs. In it I have an API that gets data from a AWS database table and populates a state array which then populates a tables. 
I cant figure out how to let a user in turn update the values of the table and then save those changes and let the API upload it back into the data base. 
I have a update method but it gives an error saying that I cant update the state Array or would complain that the column array is undefined.

I have the following code:

```
export default function Complaints(props) {

    const [complaint, setComplaint] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isInEditMode, setIsEditMode] = useState(false);
    const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState("");

    var columsArr = [
        { title: 'Customer ID', field: 'id' },
        { title: 'Issue', field: 'complaintName' },
        { title: 'Description', field: 'complaintDescription'},
        { title: 'Order ID', field: 'complaintOrderId'},
        { title: 'Submitted', field: 'createdAt'},
        { title: 'Updated', field: 'updatedAt'},
        { title: 'Admin Comment', field: 'adminComment'},
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoad() {
            if (!props.isAuthenticated) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                const complaint = await loadComplaint();
                setComplaint(complaint);
                setState({
                    columns: [state.columns, ...columsArr],
                    complaint: [...state.complaint, ...complaint]
                });
                console.log(complaint)
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);
        }

        onLoad();
    }, [props.isAuthenticated]);

    function loadComplaint() {
        return API.get("kleen", "/Complaint");
    }

    // function edit(adminComment) {
    //     setIsEditMode(true);
    //     setDefaultValue(adminComment);
    //     console.log("value is"+ adminComment);
    // }

    // function updateComplaint() {
    //     return API.put("kleen", `/Complaint/${props.}`);
    // }

    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        columns: [],
        complaint: []
});

    return (
        <MaterialTable style={{
            marginTop: "8rem",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            position: "sticky",
        }}
            title="Complaints"
            columns={state.columns}
            data={state.complaint}
            editable={{
                onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                    new Promise(resolve => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            resolve();
                            if (oldData) {
                                let key = 1;
                                setState(prevState => {
                                    complaint: prevState.complaint.map(el => el.key === key ? {...el, adminComment: "testing"}: el)
                                    // const data = [...prevState.data];
                                    // data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                    // return { ...prevState, data };
                                });
                            }
                        }, 600);
                    }),
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

I am very new to Reactjs, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can achieve is by:

1. First store the state in a variable
2. Update the array variable
3. Restore the variable to the state.

Comment: Would updating the state also automatically re-render the table with the updated data? Also I am using MaterialTable, how can I get it update just the array value that was changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use state then better to use component class

```
export default class Complaints extends Component {

//assign initial value to state
state={
    propsObj : this.props
}


...
}
```

If you want to use component you have to import it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

inside component class you have to use `this.props` instead of `props`

later if you want to change state just use `this.setState({ propsObj: 'some thing new'});`